# Use Spring Integration Aggregator in Clustered Environment pointing to same MessageStore

Tags: redis, spring-integration

We have Spring Integration Aggregator component running in multiple instances but all pointing to same JDBCMessageStore (oracle). I know we can set Region based on hostname in order for Aggregator to aggregate messages related to particular host.

But is there any way we can use DEFAULT region across all instances and still only one instance aggregate all messages in the message store?

I was reading about "Redis Lock Registry", “Gemfire Lock Registry” and  “Zookeeper Lock Registry”. Do they require their relative MessageStore to be created/configured? or Can I use them with existing JDBCMessageStore(oracle).

Are there any disadvantages using the above Lock Registry Mechanisms?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Gary. What are these different LockRegistry's used for?                                                                          https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator

(20) A reference to a org.springframework.integration.util.LockRegistry bean; used to obtain a Lock based on the groupId for concurrent operations on the MessageGroup. By default, an internal DefaultLockRegistry is used. Use of a distributed LockRegistry, such as the ZookeeperLockRegistry, ensures only one instance of the aggregator will operate on a group concurrently. See Section 24.11, “Redis Lock Registry”, Section 16.6, “Gemfire Lock Registry”, Section 37.3, “Zookeeper Lock Registry” for more information.

Comment: Don't ask questions with another answer - I don't get a notification and it's just plain wrong. Use comments instead. The `LockRegistry` is used internally in the aggregator to prevent multiple updates to the same group. If you want to use the same region across multiple instances, you must use a shared lock registry. But, in that case, any instance can add to, and/or release, the group. You can use a single region but only if you can be sure that each groupid (correlation) can only ever be used by one instance. In that case, you don't need a shared lock registry.

Comment: Sorry for that. Thank you for your input on this Gary.

Answer (score 0):

They won't help; you need to use different regions. If you use the same region across instances, you must use a shared lock registry but, in that case, any instance can add to, and/or release a group of messages.